# Using Tikz to plot the numerical grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I wonder if we have any library to plot this fig in Tikz or the way to plot them

Comment: What have you got so far? I would just plot the four nodes and their label `[above right]`, draw a rectangle with `{time}` and your title as `node [midway, above]` of their respective sides, and finally have the 8 ticks plotted eventually using a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some (rough, likely not optimal) attempt:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sffamily\tiny
    \fill (0,0) circle (.07) node [above right] {$\mathsf{T[n,j]}$};
    \fill (-2,0) circle (.07) node [above right] {$\mathsf{T[n,j\!-\!1]}$};
    \fill (2,0) circle (.07) node [above right] {$\mathsf{T[n,j\!+\!1]}$};
    \fill (0,2) circle (.07) node [above right] {$\mathsf{T[n\!+\!1,j]}$};
    \draw (-2,0) -- (0,0) -- (2,0) (0,2) -- (0,0);
    \foreach \x in {-2,0,2}
        \draw [thin,gray] (\x,-0.5) -- (\x,-0.45) (\x,2.5) -- (\x,2.45);
    \foreach \x in {0,2}
        \draw [thin,gray] (-3,\x) -- (-2.95,\x) (2.95,\x) -- (3,\x);
    \draw (-3,-0.5) -- node [midway, above, sloped] {time} (-3,2.5) -- node [midway,above] {FTCS explicit scheme} (3,2.5) -- (3,-0.5) -- cycle node [midway,below] {space};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image: FTCS grid]

Feel free to ask in comments if anything is unclear.

Comment: You missed the `space` node... lol Nice job!

Comment: Oops indeed, added! ^^

Comment: yes, thank you so much !!!

Comment: however, I tried your code but it did not run

Comment: @user Sorry, it was missing the first line. Basically you just need `\usepackage{tikz}` withing any document class.